# Display name of client with longest period reservation in ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Question: Display the name of the client who has booked the reservation for the longest period.

Tables provided,

```
CLIENT (ClientNo, Name, Sex, DOB, Address, Phone, Email, Occupation,
MaritalStatus, Spouse, Anniversary)

RESERVATION (ResNo, ResDate, NoOfGuests, StartDate, EndDate,
ClientNo, Status)
```

What i did so far is this,

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT C.Name
  FROM Client C, Reservation R
  Where C.ClientNo = R.ClientNo
  ORDER BY R.EndDate - R.StartDate DESC)
  WHERE rownum = 1;
```

It gives me the result I want but I was told "No built-in ORACLE column numbering (such as ROWNUM) or other Oracle ranking facilities
(such as RANK) can be used here."

Comment: Hint: use the MAX() function

Comment: Why do you post descriptions (well, lists of column names) of twenty tables when you only need two?

Comment: @dnoeth, you actually counted :-) My guess would be that it's from a homework assignment. But either way, I'd rather have some extra information than having to ask for the different pieces of data model again and again.

Comment: Thank you @StephaneM, It worked with MAX() function :

Comment: @dnoeth, Sorry, now i edited to the required tables.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i solved it. Thanks for the hints guys. I used the MAX() function.

```
SELECT C.Name
FROM Client C, Reservation R
WHERE C.ClientNo = R.ClientNo AND
R.EndDate-R.StartDate = (
SELECT MAX(R.EndDate-R.StartDate)
FROM Reservation R);
```